# Vbscript Wscript.Run method stuck because of space character

Tags: dom, vbscript, hta

**Error** System can't find the file specified

```
strCline = Document.getElementById("head").innerHtml
msgbox strCline
strCline = replace(strCline, " ",Chr(32))
oShell.run strCline
Set oShell = Nothing
```

Above code produces error because it can't read file name properly. It's all because of space characters in file name. After reading, i found chr(32) would replace space character but it won't. How do I make it take space character.

**Edit:**
My final code looked like this which worked. I made mistake while creating object.

```
Sub funEdit
set oShell=createobject("Wscript.shell")
strCline = Document.getElementById("head").innerHtml
msgbox strCline
strCline = replace(strCline, " ",Chr(32))
oShell.run strCline
Set oShell = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You'll have to double quote file specs containing spaces. Post (typical) content of strCline.

Comment: I didn't get you. Are you suggesting 1. "strLine" 2. strCline = replace(strCline, " ","  ") or another one?
strCline may have values like: "first text" or "second text file".
I don't why spaces get dropped while oShell.Run get executes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell splits a command line into parameters using blank(s) for a delimiter. If you want to send text file specifications to .Run to display them automagically in the default editor, you must double quote the (logically) single parameter. This demo code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim sFSpec : sFSpec = "C:\Documents and Settings\eh\tmp.txt"
Dim sCmd   : sCmd     = sFSpec
Dim oWSH   : Set oWSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
On Error Resume Next
 oWSH.Run sCmd
 WScript.Echo qq(sCmd), "=>", Err.Number, Err.Description
 Err.Clear
 sCmd = qq(sFSpec)
 oWSH.Run sCmd
 WScript.Echo qq(sCmd), "=>", Err.Number, Err.Description
On Error GoTo 0

Function qq(s)
  qq = """" & s & """"
End Function
```

will output:

```
"C:\Documents and Settings\eh\tmp.txt" => -2147024894
""C:\Documents and Settings\eh\tmp.txt"" => 0
```

and open only **one** Notepad.

See [here](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/How-To-Quote-Like-A-Pro-m81189.aspx) for some context.