# VBS How to call cmd.exe using a string variable with spaces

Tags: vbscript, cmd

I need to call the following:

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "cmd /c copy /y C:\input\" & WScript.Arguments(0) & " C:\output", 0
```

where the input argument may be "File Name.txt". I have seen countless examples of people doing the same thing using double quotes for a hard coded file location, but nothing using an input argument or variable. What syntax is required so that the command line receives:

```
copy /y "C:\input\File Name.txt" C:\output
```

and not

```
copy /y C:\input\File Name.txt C:\output
```

for an arbitrary file name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embed the needed quotes (escaped via doubling) in the surrounding literals:

```
WshShell.Run "cmd /c copy /y ""C:\input\" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """ C:\output", 0
```

[background](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/How-To-Quote-Like-A-Pro-m81189.aspx), [further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17284837/603855)

Comment: That worked perfectly, I can't believe I wasn't able to figure that out. Thank you.