# Pass variables as parameters

Tags: vbscript

Suppose I want to pass variables as my parameters, is it possible?

Example:

```
newva = 10 
obj = newobj.Run("%comspec% /c ruby E:\rubyfile.rb newva > D:\newdoc.txt", 1, true)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: It's the classic string concatenation issue, this question has been answered so many times before.

Comment: 2 minutes and [found these](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+vbscript+run+variable&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+vbscript+run+variable&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.10778j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), take your pick!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute commands with variables as path in vbscript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694523/how-to-execute-commands-with-variables-as-path-in-vbscript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate the variable's value into the command line:

```
obj = newobj.Run("%comspec% /c ruby E:\rubyfile.rb " & newva & " > D:\newdoc.txt", 1, true)
```

(Still using the bad variable names?)

Comment: Thank you  for your help :)

Comment: You've already answered this before here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26894257/692942