# File found with relative path but not absolute path? (VBS)

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to launch a shortcut from VBScript, but I am running into a very odd error.

When I use the relative path of the shortcut, the script opens the shortcut perfectly fine. However, if I use the absolute file path (copied from windows explorer so no typos or anything like that) it gives me an error saying file not found.

Relative path code:

```
dim x
set x = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
x.Run("Shortcut.lnk")
set x = Nothing
```

This opens the file.

Absolute path code:

```
dim x
set x = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
x.Run("C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Test\Shortcut.lnk")
set x = Nothing
```

As you can see, the code is exactly the same. However, it gives me a file not found error:

```
Script: C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Test\test.vbs
Line: 3
Char: 1
Error: The system cannot find the file specified.
Code: 80070002
Source: (null)
```

The file path for the script is exactly the same in the error as the path I have put in the code, but it still gives me an error.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Note:** My username has been replaced with ***** just for the question.

Comment: `****` means nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the shell (.Run, .Exec) pathes containing spaces need quotes. So replace

```
x.Run("C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Test\Shortcut.lnk")
```

with

```
x.Run """C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Test\Shortcut.lnk"""
```

(cf [here](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/How-To-Quote-Like-A-Pro-m81189.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17284837/603855))

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had no idea, I thought the single quotes would be enough but I guess the string itself needs to have quotes in it...